# Radius around a point not center when float

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I do this and it works lovely:

```
            var radiusMi = parseFloat(obj[8]);
            if (typeof radiusMi === 'undefined' || isNaN(radiusMi) || radiusMi == '') {
                radiusMi = 2;
            }
            var radiusMeters = radiusMi * 1609.344;
            var currentShape = new google.maps.Circle({
                map: map,
                radius: radiusMeters,
                strokeWeight: 0,
                fillColor: '#eb278d',
                fillOpacity: 0.25,
                center: circleLatLng
            });
```

The problem comes when the `radiusMi` is a float or under 1 mile, it becomes off center. See image below to see what I mean (`radiusMi` is set to 0.5 here):

[image]
<sub>(source: [giodev.com](http://giodev.com/map-thing.png))</sub>

The little house icon is in the correct spot, but it's not the center point to the circle, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try checking the value of circleLatLng. That might differ and if you have rounding errors, it might be off by a few percentage points.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets I'm an idiot. You were right. One of the guys I work with had some code messing with `circleLatLng`. Thanks for the help! Don't know how I missed it. Please post as the answer so I can give you the credit.

Comment: Knowing how you set the value of circleLatLng would probably help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lattitudes and longitudes are very precise floating point numbers.
When you do calculations with those numbers rounding errors can occur because of calls to round, floor, ceil, or by simple sending it to the server and retrieving it.

A lot of things can cause the accuracy to go from for example 8 digits behind the dot to 6 digits behind the dot, which would result in a difference of several ten's of meters or even hundreds of meters depending on the accuracy loss.

I suggest that you check all the spots where your  `circleLatLng` is used in code before being used here. because there could be rounding errors in play.

Make sure the `circleLatLng` doesn't contain rounding errors which could put the circle center off it's original place. Best would be at the start of your code to make a copy of it for explicit use in this part of the code, and have a different copy ready for arbitary calculations.